# MkDocs and MathJax

Tags: python, markdown, mathjax

I'm new to MkDocs and am writing some technical documentation that requires latex. I've successfully built a small website with one of the MkDocs themes, however it won't properly display the latex equations. I followed the instructions at:

http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/developers/

as well as the instructions following the python-markdown-mathjax link from that page. I have also tinkered with adding appropriate lines to my mkdocs.yaml file, similar to:

https://github.com/EdyJ/vehicle-physics-docs/blob/master/mkdocs.yml

However, issuing the command 'mkdocs build' still results in a site that doesn't render the equations. I've also tried adding a -x mathjax flag with the mkdocs build command.

I've scoured the web and have been tinkering for quite a bit of time now. Can anyone shed light on what I need to do to get these two playing together?

Comment: While you pointed to all the instructions you are trying to follow, you didn't tell us what you actually did. Therefore it is a little hard to see what you missed.

Comment: Also, I would suggest staying clear of that mathjax extension. I just looked at it closely for the first time and it has many issues: 1) it has no license, 2) it outputs invalid html, 3) the install process is ridiculous (not the recommended way to install Python-Markdown extensions), 4) its using deprecated features of Python-Markdown that will stop working in the next release, and 5) it doesn't appear to be maintained any more.

Comment: @Waylan
Could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @stefanjunker try this one: https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math

Answer (score 40):

This is actually easier than I expected. First I installed the [Python-Markdown-Math Extension](https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math):

```
pip install https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math/archive/master.zip
```

Then I created a new MkDocs project:

```
mkdocs new test_math
```

Next I edited the `test_math/docs/index.md` file to be as follows (sample borrowed from the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#tex-and-latex-input)):

```
# MathJax Test Page

When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
```

Finally, I edited the `test_math/config.yaml` file to be as follows:

```
site_name: Test Math

extra_javascript: 
    - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML

markdown_extensions:
    - mdx_math
```

I was unsure if this would work, but I ran the test server to see:

```
mkdocs serve
```

I then opened my browser and loaded http://127.0.0.1:8000/. The page displayed with the sample equations properly formatted:

[image: Mkdocs MathJax Example]

Then I remembered that the OP asked for this to work with ReadTheDocs, so I added the following line to the config:

```
theme: readthedocs
```

My browser reloaded and the following (properly formatted equations) displayed:

[image: MkDocs Math Test2]

I should note that I'm getting some weird error about fontawesome not loading. With the MkdDocs' theme, the equations disappear after a minute (when the error appears in the browser's console). However, in the ReadTheDocs theme, the equations display properly, even with the error. Either way, I believe this error is related to some other issue on my local machine.

Finally, the Bounty is...

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources

I don't normally advertise this, but since you asked, I am the lead developer of Python-Markdown, I work regularly with `mitya57` (the creator of Python-Markdown-Math Extension) as he is one of two other developers with commit access to Python-Markdown, and I am a contributor to MkDocs (one of those contributions being support for Python-Markdown Extensions).

Comment: Great, thanks, and thanks for your work on mkdocs! When I mentioned readthedocs I was actually talking about the site, readthedocs.org (which is a server which I think supports mkdocs), I'm not sure if it supports this...?

Comment: Worth mentioning that you pushed to pypi since posting this. Thanks! (I still think the question of getting it working on readthedocs is open, would be great to hear your thoughts.)

Comment: I don't use readthedocs.org myself, so not real familiar with their requirements. However, if the above is not working, the I suspect you would need to download and copy into your docs for the MathJax JavaScript library. The MathJax docs explain how to do that. MkDock should just copy the files on build.

Comment: I have mathjax working though the method I describe below (in my answer). It just doesn't work with the above, with no feedback.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrautzberger for the warning. I've updated the answer to reflect the URL for the new recommended CDN (`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?...`).

Comment: enable_dollar_delimiter: True #for use of inline $..$

Comment: It looks great, thanks. Is there any way to get those equations in a PDF via https://github.com/zhaoterryy/mkdocs-pdf-export-plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the extension as indicated in the github README. It sounds as if you have already done that.

Then you need to tell Mkdocs that you are using this Python Markdown extension. You would do this by having a line such as this in your mkdocs.yaml:
`markdown_extensions: [mathjax]`

The YAML configuration documentation can be found at:

- http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#formatting-options

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on any of this but the below is what worked for me.  One of my needs was to have the $...$ notation work for inline Latex, instead of \(..\) because the $ notation works directly in Jupyter notebooks and you can see what your text will look like without first running mkdocs.

For both $..$ and $$..$$ styles to work, first install `pip install --upgrade python-markdown-math`.  Then do the following:

1. Put a text file called *mathjaxhelper.js* in the /docs folder, and it should contain only the following:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
  extensions: ["MathMenu.js", "MathZoom.js"]
});
```

2. The *project.yml* file should contain the following. (replace *project.yml* with your actual yml file)

```
markdown_extensions:
    - extra
    - tables
    - mdx_math:
        enable_dollar_delimiter: True
    - fenced_code
theme: readthedocs
extra_javascript: 
    - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

I will admit I am no expert and really only cared about what worked.  It took me several hours to figure out what combination of things in the .yml and the mathjaxhelper.js file will get both $ and $$ to work.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like be that this extension is not required:

#### docs/mathjaxhelper.js

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "tex2jax": { inlineMath: [ [ '$', '$' ] ] }
});
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
  extensions: ["MathMenu.js", "MathZoom.js"]
});
```

#### mkdocs.yml

```
markdown_extensions:
  - extra
  - tables
  - fenced_code
extra_javascript:
  - https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML
  - mathjaxhelper.js
```

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: some of the characters used in the equations might be mistaken as Markdown markup by the parser. Therefore, you still need the Markdown extension to ensure that the Markdown parser will not muck up the equations. Otherwise, I expect your example will work.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what may go wrong here, could you give a failing example?

Comment: An extreme edge case was reported [here](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/379). I know I've seen other (more likely to be encountered) examples, but I can't find them now. It may be in general practice, you will not get collisions most of the time, but why risk it? Any equation which uses the [Markdown escape characters](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) is a potential collision.

Comment: Actually, the simple example in my answer (to the OP question) won't work as the backslashes before the parentheses are striped out by Markdown. See [Babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=When+%5C(a+%5Cne+0%5C)%2C+there+are+two+solutions+to+%5C(ax%5E2+%2B+bx+%2B+c+%3D+0%5C)+and+they+are%0A%24%24x+%3D+%7B-b+%5Cpm+%5Csqrt%7Bb%5E2-4ac%7D+%5Cover+2a%7D.%24%24) for an example of the output without a math specific extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get LaTeX in MkDocs with the extension **arithmatex**.

I'm answering again because I want to document a solution that doesn't link to third party sites like Cloudflare and Google.

I'm going the way with the theme named **mkdocs-material** but you can replace `theme: ...school` with `theme: readthedocs`.

First install MkDocs and create a project:
https://www.mkdocs.org/#installation.

Then install [mkdocs-material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/) and [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathjax.html) as follows.
Say the project is called *my-project*. 
Use downloads and not pip because you want to change the CDN to Cloudflare and the link to google.

```
cd my-project
git clone https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material.git
git clone https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax.git MathJax
```

Edit `mkdocs.yml` like described [under "Usage"](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/getting-started/#usage), for example:

```
site_name: My Project
pages:
    - Home: index.md
theme:
    name: null
    custom_dir: 'mkdocs-material/material'
    palette:
        primary: amber
        accent: pink
    language: de
    feature:
        tabs: true
    font: false
    logo:
        icon: school
markdown_extensions:
    - pymdownx.arithmatex
extra_javascript:
    - ../MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

You can insert some TeX in `index.md`, build the site (`mkdocs build`) and open the `index.html` to check that MathJax works.
Because it doesn't work with `mkdocs serve` I uploaded the MathJax folder and linking to it instead of the link to the local path.

```
extra_javascript:
    - https://mysite/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

To activate TeX inline with `$...$` you have to create an extra JS-file

```
cd docs
mkdir assets
touch extra.js
```

Insert the following text into `extra.js`:

```
window.MathJax = {
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [ ["$","$"], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
    displayMath: [ ["\\[","\\]"] ]
  },
  TeX: {
    TagSide: "right",
    TagIndent: ".8em",
    MultLineWidth: "85%",
    equationNumbers: {
      autoNumber: "AMS",
    },
    unicode: {
      fonts: "STIXGeneral,'Arial Unicode MS'"
    }
  },
  displayAlign: "center",
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  messageStyle: "none"
};
```

and link to it in `mkdocs.yml`. Finaly the extra_javascript section can like this:

```
extra_javascript:
    - https://mysite/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
    - assets/extra.js
```

Because we don't want to use CDN you can edit `mkdocs-material/material/base.html` and delete/uncomment the line with `<link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect" crossorigin>`.
Font-awesome and material-icons are already on board within mkdocs-material.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I found. Just add the following content into `mkdocs.yml`:

```yaml
markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.arithmatex

extra_javascript:
  - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

And then `$f(x)$` and `$$f(x)$$` will all work fine.