# mkdocs How to use German umlauts in combination with Mathjax?

Tags: special-characters, mkdocs

I want to type the following formula in mkdocs using Mathjax

```
$$\text{Volumenänderungsarbeit} & L_\text{vol} = -\int p \,dV$$
```

The problem is the German umlaut ä that I am using. If I remove it, then everything is fine. I tried to replace it but it does not work.

- \text{Volumen{\"a}nderungsarbeit}
- \text{Volumen"anderungsarbeit}
- \text{Volumen}{\"a}\text{nderungsarbeit}
- \text{Volumen\"anderungsarbeit}

Comment: Mathjax is not TeX or LaTeX. Use HTML entities like `&auml;`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution and it works. If I am writing on MathStackExchange I can simply write ä, is there a way to turn this feature on in mkdocs/HTLM?

Comment: I think you should be able to write ä but you need to use the correct encoding (likely UTF-8) whereas ampersand-entities always work.

Comment: I'm not sure how Mathjax handles Unicode characters, which may be the cause of your problem (and why I'm not providing an answer). Python-Markdown (which MkDocs uses under the hood) will properly pass Unicode characters through unaltered. It all works only if your Markdown pages and MkDocs templates are properly encoded and the resulting HTML is served with the proper encoding (usually UTF-8). However, if any one of those things is missing, it all falls down. Therefore, as the output is HTML, HTML entities are the best way to ensure they display correctly everywhere.

Comment: @Waylan: Thank you a lot for your comment. And +1 for your great answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882261/mkdocs-and-mathjax/31926644#31926644

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how to use the answers given in the comments here. I want to write the accents over the characters in stackexchange. In latex I write {\'e}. The &auml produces "&auml" so it does not work. I also have no idea how to "simply write a" (with two dots over it).  This comment section gets the "coded information" prize of passing information between two parties while ensuring zero information is obtained by an eavesdropper.